# How to add background music to gamescene in andengine

Tags: java, android, andengine, background-music

bg music plays on splash,menu and gamescene when i had put the below code, but i want to make bg music to play only on my gamescene, can you please help me. Thank you.

```
public void onCreateResources(OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback) throws IOException
    {
        MusicFactory.setAssetBasePath("mfx/");

        try {
            music = MusicFactory.createMusicFromAsset(mEngine
                    .getMusicManager(), this, "abcd.wav");
            music.setLooping(true);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
     ResourcesManager.prepareManager(mEngine, this, camera, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
  }

public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback) throws IOException
    {
         music.play();
            SceneManager.getInstance().createSplashScene(pOnCreateSceneCallback);
     }
```

Comment: Did you load the sound before starting the level?

Comment: yes, in mfx folder. bgc music plays, but i want bg music to play only on game scene, not on the splash and menu scene.

Comment: You have to unload the sound when switching scenes

Comment: how to unload? can you give the code to unload?

Comment: `music.stop();music.release();`, you probably should call these methods from your SoundManager class

Comment: i don't have soundmanager class, i had put it on gameactivity class

Comment: Make the sound play after you loaded your game scene, I had a resource manager class which called the appropriate sound from the constructor of my game scene class when it is being created.

Comment: can you provide the code using gamescene and resource manager class, i have both the class, but don't know how to write bgmusic code on that.

Comment: Hi kabuto, can you please help me out??

Comment: Within the gamescene maybe in its constructor you can do `ResourceManager.loadSoundForGameScene()` to load your new audio, in the ResourceManager class you should have your code to play the audio so when you call the method `loadSoundForGameScene()` the correct sound will be played. Additionally when your scene is being changed you should have a method to stop and unload the sound resources as well in order to keep sound in the gamescene only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use `music.pause()` and `music.resume()` (because after stop the play does not work any more, I do not know why). When you leave a scene, you can call `music.pause()`. When you enter a scene, you can call `music.resume();`